# iOS React Native - navigation doesn't work using native code

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm in the middle of trying to make multiple frameworks to work together in an iOS environment and I got stuck while trying to navigate using a native method triggered by React Native (RN).

After trying multiple ways of doing this (one of them being exposing the `rootViewController` and change the `UIViewController` in the triggered method) I just can't change the view controller, even though the method is being called.

I'll leave some code that I tried below and hopefully better explain what I'm trying to do.

*Disclaimer: I'm a beginner with obj-c and a complete noob with iOS development - learning as I go*

This is my `AppDelegate` implementation:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [super applicationDidFinishLaunching:application];  

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"SomethingMobile"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;


  self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:   rootViewController];
  [self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];

//--- style the UINavigationController
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Home";

  return YES;
}

-(void) changeView {
 // SimpleViewController is a valid UIViewController that I tested separately and it works
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[SimpleViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"OF";
  printf("Got here");
}

@end
```

Then I have a class that acts as a bridge between RN and the native code:

```
@implementation OFStarter

// The React Native bridge needs to know our module
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport {
  return @{@"greeting": @"Welcome to native"};
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(squareMe:(int)number:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {

  AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  [delegate changeView]; // this is getting called when I press a button in the RN view
  callback(@[[NSNull null], [NSNumber numberWithInt:(number*number)]]);
}

@end
```

Now for some reason unknown to me, when the `changeView` method is called nothing is happening. From my understanding, the `pushViewController` is the method to call when changing the view using a `UINavigationController`.

Now if I want to change the view controller in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method using the same line of code as in the `changeView`, it works perfectly.

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[SimpleViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];`

To make matters even weirder, one time I was clicking on the RN button annoyed for about 20 times and then all of a sudden the view started to change ~20 times.

Also, I want to mention that the `changeView` is always getting called when I press the RN button.

I would appreciate any help on this matter. I was stuck on this for some time and I'm pretty sure I might be missing something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem in the end. When changing the ViewController you have to do so from the main thread otherwise it doesn't work as expected.

All I needed to do was to add this method to the `OFStarter` implementation:

```
- (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
{
  return dispatch_get_main_queue();
}
```